# How do you switch scenes in Unity 2D on collison

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

I was wondering how I can switch scenes in my 2D Unity game. I put the scenes in the build and the objects are entering in colison. I used this code but it didn't worked:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class SceneSwitch : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private string WhatScene;

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene(WhatScene);
        }
    }
}
```

Can you help me?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpg3t.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HoOfl.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GEgi.png

Comment: You need to write details, is it entering the collision? Have you put the scenes in the build settings?

Comment: I put the scenes in the build and it is entering the colision.

Comment: What happens when a GameObject with tag "Player" enters the trigger than?

Comment: And what is this script attached to?

Comment: It is attached to the trigger sprite

Comment: Please change your questions and put screenshots and details, or we can't help you

Comment: I attached screen shots.

Answer (score 0):

Note that there is

- [`OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter2D.html) which as parameter takes a `Collider2D`, **not `Collider`**. This one is for 2D physics using `Rigidbody2D` and `Collider2D` components.
- [`OnTriggerEnter(Collider)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter.html) which takes a `Collider`, **not `Collider2D`. This one is for 3D physics using `Rigidbody` and `Collider` components.

Since you are talking about 2D your method should look like

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(WhatScene);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using OnTriggerEnter method in unity2D there is a problem, you need to set collision as a trigger and use "OnTriggerEnter2D" method.
In build settings you have to add scenes, there will be a different index attributed to every scenes.

```html
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider other)
{
    if (other.CompareTag("TAG"))
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene([INDEX OF THE SCENE YOU WANT TO USE]);
    }
}
```

If you want to detect a collision use OnCollisionEnter2D.